# How to solve 'Connection refused' errors in SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have an Ubuntu Server 10.10 32-bit in my home. I'm making SSH connections to it from my PC via Putty.

The problem is, sometimes I'm able to login seamlessly. However, sometimes it gives me an error like this: `Network error: Connection refused.`

Then, I dont't change anything, try to login a few times more, wait a while and try again. Sometimes I can log in, sometimes I cannot. It seems pretty random to me.

What can I do to solve this?

Edit:

And Sometimes, Putty gives `Network error: Software caused connection abort` error after displaying `login as:` text.

Here is the ping -t output:

```
Pinging 192.168.2.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=65ms TTL=6
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=88ms TTL=6
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.2.254: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

---

I turned off firewall of router, and everything seems to work now. Except for that, I still can't enter my web server by typing external IP from my PC.

Comment: next time it craps out like that; run a ping on it again, does it still work? how many people ssh to this machine?

Comment: Only I ssh this server.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, also getting a mix of successful connects (which then work for hours), 'connection refused' and 'software caused connection abort' after the login or password entry. To provide some additional details: in my case it's a 64-bit virtual machine (running Ubuntu Server 10.10) on a Microsoft Hyper-V host, using the "old network card" emulation.

Comment: SSH is installed on your server?

Comment: use the command below to restart ssh service

service sshd restart

Answer (score 117):

You must install openssh-server on Linux before this will work.  Get the internal IP address of Ubuntu and use that IP to setup port forwarding on port 22 (SSH) section of your router.  Although if you don't intend to SSH from outside your network, this is not required.

Here's how to install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
[ENTER PASSWORD]
```

Comment: Does not answer the question directly but this is useful as Ubuntu does not come pre-installed with SSH server.

Comment: I recently got a new laptop and totally forgot it's not installed by default  =D

Comment: This not only doesn't answer the question directly, it's just plain wrong. The OP has an intermittent problem using SSH, so obviously the server _is_ installed.

Comment: In our case, I used the following to solve the "unmet dependencies" errors: 

`sudo aptitude install openssh-server`

Answer (score 56):

IP address conflict turned out to be the root cause when I was seeing this SSH error message.

After reading the answers above I suspected an IP address conflict, but needed to prove that address conflict was or was not the problem.

This [great article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150707051826/http://techthrob.com/2010/06/identifying-and-resolving-ip-address-conflicts-with-linux/) showed how to use arp-scan to see if two pieces of hardware were claiming the same IP address.

In my case the server machine had a static ip address  of 192.168.1.42, I used arp-scan to check that address:

```
$ sudo apt-get install arp-scan
$ arp-scan -I eth0 -l | grep 192.168.1.42
  192.168.1.42 d4:eb:9a:f2:11:a1 (Unknown)
  192.168.1.42 f4:23:a4:38:b5:76 (Unknown) (DUP: 2)
```

Sure enough there was a conflict, as shown above.  Then I ran arp-scan without the grep, found that .43 was available, went and edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and changed the static ip from .42 to .43

Comment: Actually running that command showed only one line on my box, except that the name was that of another device.

Comment: Thank you so much for the point in the right direction about IP address conflict. Had a similar problem! +1

Comment: Just saved me so much time... kudos...

Comment: Sometimes my router just needs to be restarted to solve this issue.

Comment: yep. Had to tell my wife to restart wifi on her iphone. Restarting a router would fix it too

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Chasing my tail for ages!

Comment: Another +1 from me, sometimes the obvious stuff causes the most trouble

Answer (score 21):

Use [`arping`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/arping.8.html) on the IP address that is having connection issues. That will show the MAC address for each ping reply, and hopefully will unmask the rogue MAC address.

```
arping 192.168.2.254
```

You should check the DHCP IP address pool on the DHCP server, make sure no devices have static IPs that collide with the DHCP pool.

These clues point to duplicate IP:

- ping ttl and round trip time looks like 2 distinct servers
- intermittent disconnects without rebooting

Comment: I needed to add -I wlan0 (wlan0 being my wifi device)

Answer (score 21):

open the file of ssh config:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

find the port

```
#port 22
```

uncomment (remove the `#`) the port option

then save the file by <kbd>ctrl + x</kbd> and restart your service

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: This was the problem for me on a freshly installed Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Comment: Did not help me.

Comment: "Failed to restart ssh.service. Unit ssh.service not found"

Comment: @KansaiRobot Should be `sshd.service`. `sshd` is the server, `ssh` is the client

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, even though I had a static IP address. Turns out another server on my network had been assigned the same (static) IP address. (Duh.) So it does appear that the problem is caused by IP address conflicts, but there may be various possible ways they can happen. If you set yours to static and still have a problem, try shutting down your machine and pinging the address. If you get any replies, start looking for what else could have the same address.

Answer (score 8):

What do you get if you do this?

```
grep 192.168.2.25 /etc/hosts.deny
```

If that returns anything then you need to remove it.

Comment: That's one of the infamous "useless uses of `cat`" - you can simply `grep 192.168.2.25 /etc/hosts.deny`

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Fixed it

Comment: Opening the file in an editor is likely to be easier to see what's going on in there. Also in my case the content was: `ALL: ALL EXCEPT localhost` (GParted default setup). All I had to do is add my IP address to the list of exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

This looks more of a problem of your network equipment than the server itself.

Check /var/log/messages for ethernet link up/downs (or wlan in case of wireless). If so try changing the cables.

Comment: Yes, i tried and succeeded in making an ssh connection from outside of my network (which my server and my PC are located in). It seems working well. My server is also a web server. When I try to connect over port 80 from my PC, i see my ADSL modem's login page. But when I try the same thing from another computer which is outside my network, I see Apache's It Works page.

Comment: What is you PC ip, your server ip and your internal adsl router ip?

Comment: PC: 192.168.2.2 (Received from DHCP)
Server: 192.168.2.254 (Static, out of DHCP range)
ADSL Router: 192.168.2.1

Comment: I'm a bit confused, when you connect from 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.254 port 80 you get the adsl modem's login?

Comment: Yes, that's correct forcefsck.

Comment: Unless you have setup some kind of web proxy to your server, then clearly your adsl modem is responding to requests made to 192.168.2.254 and probably that's the case when you get the `Connection refused` error with ssh. So you have to recheck the settings of your adsl modem.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm this exact issue: It's not a simple connectivity issue. The ethernet link does not change state; server is reachable via ping; ssh connects flawlessly occasionally, then seemingly randomly does not connect or existing ssh session drops. This occurs on Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.04. Following hheimbuerger's suggestion I gave the server a static IP, this seemed to fix it.

Workaround: Change adapter from DHCP to static.

Answer (score 4):

It's basically because of any one of the following reasons:

1. Too many users on the network trying to access the server
2. More than one computer on the network has the same IP as the server causing an IP conflict
3. Wrong username or your credentials have been revoked

Answer (score 3):

On my case, `fail2ban` had banned my IP:

1. `iptables -n -L` (use this command to see if you were banned by this ****** or something else)
2. https://bobcares.com/blog/fail2ban-unban-ip/

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check your `iptables` rules on your server. It sounds like you've a rule for limiting new SSH connections.

The next rule allows 5 new connections per minute, if you exceed this limit, your new connections will be rejected after some time has passed:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 5/min -j ACCEPT
```

See the [IPTables / Netfilter documentation](http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3), scroll a bit till `limit`.

Comment: Related, I found my `ufw` was blocking incoming data on port 22 by `sudo ufw disable`.  By default `ufw` blocks *all* incoming ports. Solution was `sudo ufw allow ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, and in my case it turned out to be an IP address conflict. My Ubuntu VM had a dynamic address, but another machine (in this case a phone) had a static IP assigned that the DHCP server did not know about.

Just changing the IP that was assigned by the DHCP server to the Ubuntu VM fixed all connection issues.

Answer (score 2):

arp-scan is showing two duplicate devices, but when I run Advanced IP scanner on Win8 they all look fine.  So they don't always agree.

I set the router to revoke all the leases by telling it to give  only 1-hour leases.  Will give it time to see if it clears up.

Answer (score 0):

On Manjaro, while `sshd` is installed by default, the server daemon was not actice.

`sudo systemctl start sshd.service` opened it immediately, and works out of the box.