# I am not able to login to another laptop

Tags: 12.04, ssh, remote-access, sshd

I am using this command:

```
userA :~$ sudo ssh userB@192.168.1.3
```

It says ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.3 port 22: connection refused.

I want to login remote & this is not working. In a forum they said that if in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if i change it to port 2222 it would work, but its still not working.

After this i want to transfer some of my media files to other laptop. Can anyone help me with that too? Thank you.

PS: I am using Ubuntu Maverick and he is on 12.04.

Comment: Please check this: http://askubuntu.com/a/104768/9701 for `connection refuse` issue.

Comment: This too http://askubuntu.com/a/141415/9701

Comment: Good to hear that. Which one solved the problem? Can you post your solution as answer here and accept it? It will help others faced the same issue ;)

Comment: It says i can aceept my own answer in two days. so in two days i'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not installed openssh-server on my laptop.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

should do the trick, also make sure that openssh-server is installed on all the systems you are trying to login to.